# Prove that the given series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{ n}\right) ^2$$ is convergent.

I tried by using some comparison like $\ln n <n$ but couldn't get the conclusive relation. I also tried to use integral test but it was no use. Any hint?

Comment: Then try $\ln n \leq n^{1/3}$. (For $n$ big enough)

Comment: yes...done!!!!.

Comment: So, if you don't see what to do immediately, in order: $\ln n \leq n$, not enough. $\ln n \leq n^{1/2}$, not enough, but close. $\ln n \leq n^{1/3}$, enough. ($n^{0.499999}$ would have been enough too, but less natural to try.)

Comment: yes..got it....

Comment: That's $\zeta''(2)$, hence yes, it is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Show that there exists $N>1$ such that for all $n>N$
$$(\ln n)^2\leq \sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: I agree with the inequality for sufficiently large n but how can we show that?

Comment: Evaluate the limit of $\frac{(\ln n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$ as $n\to+\infty$ and then use the definition of limit.